# String Split for only first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I want to split the below input string as output string.
Input = 'ABC1:ABC2:ABC3:ABC4'
Output = ['ABC1','ABC2:ABC3:ABC4']

```
let a = 'ABC1:ABC2:ABC3:ABC4'
a.split(':', 2); // not working returning ['ABC1','ABC2']
```

Comment: https://es6console.com/j4zc4icr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this, works in all browsers

```js
var nString = 'ABC1:ABC2:ABC3:ABC4';
var result = nString.split(/:(.+)/).slice(0,-1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let a = 'ABC1:ABC2:ABC3:ABC4'
const head = a.split(':', 1);
const tail = a.split(':').splice(1);

const result = head.concat(tail.join(':'));
console.log(result); // ==> ["ABC1", "ABC2:ABC3:ABC4"]
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4nq1tLye/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
var a = 'ABC1:ABC2:ABC3:ABC4';

var indexToSplit = a.indexOf(':');
var first = a.slice(0, indexToSplit);
var second = a.slice(indexToSplit + 1);

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log('ABC1:ABC2:ABC3:ABC4'.replace(':','@').split('@'));
```